# Compare list/IEnumerable type properties in Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to compare the object which contains `List<>` type properties. I am able to compare the simple properties but got stuck with complex one.

```
 foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
     {
        object oldValue = pi.GetValue(oldObject), newValue = pi.GetValue(newObject);
        if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
        {
           Type type = oldValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

           /* Need something like below commented line.*/
           // var added = newValue.Except(oldValue)
           // var removed = oldValue.Except(newValue);
        }}
```

In if block, i need to find the added and removed object in List type properties. In object we have Key attributed property to find added and removed object.

Comment: So, is the type of the item in the list is known in advance? Should items be compared by a Key property only?

Comment: List type is not know because i am trying to create generic method.
Yes,  item should be compared by key Attribute. We do not need to look for other properties.

Comment: If you try to create a generic method for any type of item, but yet you say that you have Key... attribute? or property? -- you need to constrain the item type to an ancestor that has that Key property

Comment: one property in item will have the [Key] attribute. so that we can find the added or removed items based on this Key attributed property. We do not need to compare the complete item.

Comment: Ah, ok. I will update the answer.

Comment: Done. please check the updated answer

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to compare to what? Also, how do you know there will only be one generic argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is the complete solution according to my understanding of the question.

here is the key attribute that designates key property of an item:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class KeyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

For test, let's say we have a class named `SomeClass`, which contains a `List<>` property, and an item class named `SomeItem`, which contains one key property, and additional properties ignored by comparison:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public List<SomeItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class SomeItem
{
    [Key]
    public int TheKey { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the function that performs the comparison:

```
public void CompareNewWithOld(object oldObject, object newObject, List<object> added, List<object> removed)
{
    var properties = typeof (SomeClass).GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
    {
        object oldValue = pi.GetValue(oldObject), newValue = pi.GetValue(newObject);
        if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
        {
            var itemType = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var itemKeyProperty = itemType
                .GetProperties()
                .FirstOrDefault(ipi => ipi.GetCustomAttribute<KeyAttribute>() != null);

            if (itemKeyProperty == null)
            {
                continue; // no Key property -- cannot compare
            }

            var comparer = new ItemByKeyEqualityComparer(itemKeyProperty);

            HashSet<object> oldSet = new HashSet<object>(((IEnumerable)oldValue).Cast<object>(), comparer);
            HashSet<object> newSet = new HashSet<object>(((IEnumerable)newValue).Cast<object>(), comparer);

            HashSet<object> removedSet = new HashSet<object>(oldSet, comparer);
            removedSet.ExceptWith(newSet);

            HashSet<object> addedSet = new HashSet<object>(newSet, comparer);
            addedSet.ExceptWith(oldSet);

            added.AddRange(addedSet);
            removed.AddRange(removedSet);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to conveniently compare item objects by their key property with `HashSet<T>`, we also need to implement an equality comparer class, as follows:

```
public class ItemByKeyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    private readonly PropertyInfo _keyProperty;
    public ItemByKeyEqualityComparer(PropertyInfo keyProperty)
    {
        _keyProperty = keyProperty;
    }
    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        var kx = _keyProperty.GetValue(x);
        var ky = _keyProperty.GetValue(y);
        if (kx == null)
        {
            return (ky == null);
        }
        return kx.Equals(ky);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        var key = _keyProperty.GetValue(obj);
        return (key == null ? 0 : key.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

and here is a test that passes:

```
[Test]
public void TestCompareNewWithOld()
{
    var oldObject = new SomeClass() {
        Items = new List<SomeItem>() {
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 1, SomeValue = "A"},
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 2, SomeValue = "B"},
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 3, SomeValue = "C"},
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 4, SomeValue = "D"},
        }
    };
    var newObject = new SomeClass() {
        Items = new List<SomeItem>() {
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 3, SomeValue = "W"},
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 4, SomeValue = "V"},
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 5, SomeValue = "U"},
            new SomeItem() { TheKey = 6, SomeValue = "T"},
        }
    };

    var added = new List<object>();
    var removed = new List<object>();

    CompareNewWithOld(oldObject, newObject, added, removed);

    Assert.That(removed, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {
        oldObject.Items[0],  //A
        oldObject.Items[1]   //B
    }));
    Assert.That(added, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {
        newObject.Items[2],  //U
        newObject.Items[3]   //T
    }));
}
```

Comment: still isn't working though ... removed.ExceptWith(newSet); does't remove elements ..... have u tried doing this ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. Please see updated answer with a passing test. Can you give me an example that didn't work?

Comment: Working fine.. Thanks @felix-b

Answer (score 0):

Cast `oldValue` and `newValue` to `IEnumerable<Object>` and then compare them as needed:

```
if (IsGenericEnumerable(pi)) {
    IEnumerable<Object> newEnumerable = (IEnumerable<Object>) newValue;
    IEnumerable<Object> oldEnumerable = (IEnumerable<Object>) oldValue;

    // operate with newEnumerable and oldEnumerable as needed by the logic
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for value types such as int and boolean. May be you need to cast to non-generic `IEnumerable` instead.

Comment: As required functionality is newEnumerable .Except(oldEnumerable),Above cast is not helping for the same. it is returning newEnumerable not the difference.

Comment: Once values are casted to an `IEnumerable<Object>` it is possible to use the `Except` extension method from `System.Linq.Enumerable`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx. So just use

var addedValues = newEnumerable.Except(oldEnumerable);
var removedValues = oldEnumerable.Except(newEnumerable);

There could be difficulties if values in the lists are of a value type, then you would need some conversion as is discussed by felix-b.